# How to get checked event of Listview in ListFragment

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-listfragment

I have a JSONArray which adds data to `list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();`

The list display is working fine. Data is received and displayed perfectly.

But when I add a checkbox for it, the checkbox wont work. I checked some tutorials all have used ListFragment but its not working in mine.

code:

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.list );  

            // When item is tapped, toggle checked properties of CheckBox and Planet.  
            listview .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {  
              @Override  
              public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item,   
                                       int position, long id) {  
                .......
              }  
            });  


            return rootView;

        }

        class LoadMatches extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading Matches..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            // Setup the get request
                HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(URL_MATCHES);
                            try{
                                // Execute the request in the client
                                HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
                                // Grab the response
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                                json = reader.readLine();                       
                                }catch(Exception e){
                                    Log.d("Error in JSON",e.toString());
                                }

                try {               
                    istArray= new JSONArray(json);

                    if (matches != null) {
                        // looping through All albums
                        for (int i = 0; i < listArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = istArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item values in variable
                            id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                            schname = c.getString(TAG_SCHNAME);
                        place= c.getString(TAG_PLACE);
                            datetime = c.getString(TAG_DATETIME);

                           // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_SCHNAME, schname);
                            map.put(TAG_PLACE, place);
                            map.put(TAG_DATETIME, datetime);



                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            list.add(map);
                        }
                    }else{


                        Log.d("Matches: ", "null");
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all albums
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */

                         ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                getActivity(), list
                                R.layout.s_list, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_SCHNAME, TAG_PLACE, TAG_DATETIME, }, new int[] {
                                        R.id.list_id, R.id.schname, R.id.place, R.id.datetime });
                        // updating listview
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }
        }    
  }
```

The list layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white_overlay_list"
    android:divider="@color/lists_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Single list layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Album id / Hidden by default -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/schname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ndroid:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:gravity="left"
       android:textColor="@color/black_font_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datetime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black_font_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@place
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/datetime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/datetime"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

        android:textColor="@color/black_font_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
     <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="CheckBox" />      


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what issue you are getting with checkbox ?

Comment: Actually I dont know whether its the check box what ever I put inside the set on click listener app not responds

Comment: the listener you set is for listview item and not checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The click listener is set on your listview and not the actual CheckBox. You will need to somehow inside your onItemClick to get the checkbox and check it, something like:

```
 @Override  
 public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View item, int position, long id) { 

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    cb.setChecked(true);

 }
```

This is assuming that **View item** is your individual listView item

EDIT:

When you have a checkbox inside listview it will intercept the touch events. In your xml file for the list item, add the following to the  element:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Do take note that you will then have to manually set the checkbox in the onclicklistener as described in my original answer

Comment: But there is no effect i mean no result. I did it with Log.d to test it. It won;t appear when the item clicked

Comment: Ah I see! Ok, so when you say "The list display is working fine", do you mean the listView actually displays correctly with all the data, except that nothing happens when you click it?

Comment: It displays correctly. Ya not working in any click events. Im using Fragments with listview. When I use ListFragment the app stops

Comment: Ok, if the list displays correctly then I reckon this is only a typo, but in your onPostExecute() you are setting the adapter on list and it should be set on listView. Will have another look when i get home, leaving work now YEAH

Comment: Ya ok. If you can help me with a togglebutton with the checkbox in the above code.